# recycler Adapter & loaderManager, current viewing items go down when new items come in

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-loadermanager

I'm new to android.

I'm trying to create a recyclerAdapter in my app with loaderManager to load cursor from sqlite asynchronously.

When there is new data available from sqlite database, I want to insert new items on top of recyclerView. But at the same time, also want to maintain current viewing item.

Let's say, I'm currently viewing item range 5th to 10th, when new 10 items come in, current viewing position also should be 15th to 20th (not to new 5th to 10th).

Otherwise, if lots of items (50 to 60 items) insert, user will lose what he was previously looking at.

So, Is there any way that can maintain current viewing item with recyclerView and loaderManager? How Can it be done simply?

Edit

My code are still simple. Nothing complicated yet to mention specially. But if u insist, Here is my codes.

MyActivity.java

```
public class MyActivity extends BaseActivity
    implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{
private CustomAdapter mAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_layout);

    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter();
    RecyclerView recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    recycler.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    recycler.getItemAnimator().setAddDuration(1000);
    recycler.getItemAnimator().setChangeDuration(1000);
    recycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
    LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recycler.setLayoutManager(llm);
    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
}


@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if(mAdapter != null || mAdapter.getItemCount() != 0){
        mAdapter.closeCursor();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {

    return new CursorLoader(this,buildDataUri(),null,null,null,null);
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(cursor);
}

@Override
public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    mAdapter.swapCursor(null);
}
```

CustomAdapter.java

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder> {
Cursor cursor;


public void swapCursor(Cursor c){
    cursor = c;
    if(c != null){
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        ...
    }
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    CardView c = (CardView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.card_cardView, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(c);
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
    ...
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return cursor != null ? cursor.getCount() : 0;
}

public void closeCursor() {
    cursor.close();
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    ...
}
```

Comment: please post your code in order to understand what exactly you are doing

Comment: @vipul_asri. I have added code.

Comment: you declared `ProverbHistoryAdapter mAdapter` and after that you are type-casting `mAdapter` to `CustomAdapter` is it right? or you just made a mistake.

Comment: @vipul_asri ... Sorry fri.. I edited it already.. My adapter is working fine.. showing items and clickListener trigger correctly ... the problem is viewing items go down when new items comes in..

Comment: Could you also provide the code for buildDataUri as I'm stuck at this stage building URI's for SQLite. Thanks.

Comment: I used CursorLoader here because I want to update the list immediately if the data from database changed. If you want to do that, will also have to use ContentProvider. In ContentProvider, URIs are used to get data from database. after learnt ContentProvider, building uri is a piece of cake. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html

Answer (score 0):

@Zoedia I think its how it works, when new items comes in obviously your current items will scroll down.

You can try a work around by not displaying new items in `Recycler View` as it comes while giving a Floating Button from top and asking user to click on button or `Swipe-to-Refresh` to load new items. This will help you read the stuff you are currently reading and new items will be displayed (Recycler View will be inflated with new Items) as soon as user click on that button.

Its similar to Facebook Android App implementation (**New Stories** Button) :

[image]

**Edit 1:**
To add an item at a particular position, you have to add items from your loader at the 0<sup>th</sup>/initial position as you want the new feed to be at top.
After that call the `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` to reflect that changes in `Recycler view` with new elements.

If you were using the `ArrayList<>`, then you just have to call `.add(listitem,position)` method to add a single item or `.addAll(list,position)` to add all the ArrayList.
and then call `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`.

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what i'm trying to do..Thanks for the example. Facebook android app even allow user to scroll up to "New Stories" without clicking it. I want to know is how it detect the top of list and place each story one by one while scrolling. <not displaying at once>.  Is it possible with CursorLoader as in OnCreateLoader from my code and as simple as swapCursor in My "CustomAdapter"? Do i need to play with RecyclerView LayOutManager to go deeper? Coz I don't wanna go complex as long as there are simple ways.

Comment: @Zoedia please see **Edit 1**.

Comment: thank you @vipul_asri .. Now it works with notifyItemRangeInserted(0, **sizeOfNewItem**).